# input type="number" and IE10+

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, validation, input

I'm trying to do Javascript client-side validation of a number field using an HTML5 `<input type="number">` element. There is also server-side validation, so let's not start a rant about that...  ;)

I wish to provide three status levels of validation: Green for a valid number within the defined range, Yellow for an out-of-range number or an empty field, and Red for non-numeric input.

My problem is that IE11 (and, I believe, IE10) seem to return a blank `.value` property for non-numeric input. That is, if I type `abc` into the box, `.value` is `""`. That prevents me distinguishing Yellow (blank) from Red (garbage).

I'm aware of the existence of the new `.valueAsNumber` property, but that does not completely help me as I cannot distinguish between empty on other browsers and non-numeric on IE10/11 (`.value` is empty, `.valueAsNumber` is `NaN`).

Has anyone solved this problem? I don't want to resort to tracking keypresses, and I want to support older browsers (back to IE8) that revert to `type="text"` and do not have `.valueAsNumber`. Thanks in advance...

Edit: just to clarify (hopefully), my issue is that the output of `.value` and `.valueAsNumber` in IE10/11 does not allow me to distinguish between no input and  non-numeric input. I would like to be able to distinguish these two cases without browser-sniffing and falling back to `type="text"`.

Comment: Why not consider changing from permitting _blank_ to using some _default_ which is outside your range, e.g. `0`, which you can detect and make behave differently, then this enables always casting everything to _Number_ so you can always work with _Numbers_ only? (You should still do server-side validation, obviously)

Answer (score 2):

Could you not just assign a **sensible default value** (zero?) to your input class? Then you wouldn't need to make the distinction in your code in the first place?

Pragmatism always trumps ingenuity in my book ;)

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and use `valueAsNumber` in browsers that support it.

```
var
  coerced,
  value,
  input = yourInput;

if(typeof input.valueAsNumber !== "undefined") {
   value = (isNaN(input.valueAsNumber)) ? "dummystring" : input.valueAsNumber;
} else {
   value = input.value; 
}

if(typeof input.value === "string") {
 //non-numeric
} else {
 coerced = +input.value;
 //do validation on coerced - it is now a number
}
```

Browsers that support `valueAsNumber`, they also support `input[type=number]`, so this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not my issue. I cannot find a way to distinguish between blank and non-numeric input on IE11, even using `.value` and `.valueAsNumber`, as `.value` is blank in both cases.

Comment: If the value of the input is an empty string, then my tests show that IE11 returns `NaN` for `.valueAsNumber`, not blank, whatever blank is.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. An empty input field gives me an empty string for `.value` and `NaN` for `.valueAsNumber`; putting "abc" in the field gives the same results. I cannot find a way to distinguish the presence of non-numeric characters in the form field from having no input at all.