# React Warning: Unknown prop `valueAsNumber` on <input> tag

Tags: forms, reactjs, input

I have a component that wraps an `<input type=number>`.

Here is my JSX:

```
function InputNumber(props) {
    return (<input
               type="number"
               valueAsNumber={props.value}
               onChange={e => props.onChange(e.target.valueAsNumber)}
               step={props.step}
    />);
}
```

This compiles to the following JS:

```
function InputNumber(props) {
    return (React.createElement("input", {type: "number", valueAsNumber: props.value, onChange: function (e) { return props.onChange(e.target.valueAsNumber); }, step: props.step}));
}
```

React is giving me the following warning:

> Warning: Unknown prop `valueAsNumber` on  tag. Remove this prop from the element.

It seems to work fine if I read and write from `element.valueAsNumber` in the DOM, so why doesn't React know about this property?

Comment: Don't use non-standard attributes on standard HTML tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [DOM Elements Doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#all-supported-html-attributes), `valueAsNumber` is not a valid attribute. [This article also confirms](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/unknown-prop.html) that unsupported attributes are stripped.

> 3. React does not yet recognize the attribute you specified. This will likely be fixed in a future version of React. However, React currently strips all unknown attributes, so specifying them in your React app will not cause them to be rendered.

You might want to check out this repo instead:

[**react-numeric-input**](https://github.com/vlad-ignatov/react-numeric-input)

> Number input component that can replace the native number input which is not yet very well supported and where it is, it does not have the same appearance across the browsers. Additionally this component offers more flexible options and can be used for any values (differently formatted representations of the internal numeric value).

Comment: I thought React uses js properties, not html attributes. For example `<input className="foo" />` instead of ``<input class="foo" />`` because that's the js property name. After reading that doc, it sounds like they just made their own attribute names.

Comment: Yes and no. `className` is special because `class` is a JS reserved word. They use camelCase props that are convererted to the HTML attributes. But they only pass through the supported ones.

Comment: I just assumed they were doing `var div = document.createElement('div'); div.className="foo";` but now that I think about it, they must emit HTML for server side rendering so now it make sense why they don't support `valueAsNumber` since its not an attribute :(

Comment: Not sure your scenario, but you should still be able set the value, but access `valueAsNumber` from the onChange event by calling `event.currentTarget.valueAsNumber`.

Comment: Reading is fine, but I need to write to `valueAsNumber` due to an [IE bug](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number). "IE10 and IE11 also have broken .valueAsNumber results that don't follow the spec, e.g. for 
input.value = '9' input.valueAsNumber returns NaN"

Comment: So are you attempting more of a IE polyfill? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858974/input-type-number-and-ie10

Answer (score 1):

To use non-standard attributes on React components without having them stripped, you must follow HTML 5 standard and prefix them with "data-" and don't use camel case.  So yours would be:

```
data-value-as-number={props.value}
```

Comment: W3C Recommendation 28 October 2014 : [type=number](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state-(type=number)) AND [valueAsNumber](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-valueasnumber)

Answer (score 1):

As Jeff McCloud said, you are going to use non standard html attributes. Your function may be rewritten like this:

```
function InputNumber(props) {
    return (<input
               type="number"
               data-valueAsNumber={props.value}
               onChange={e => props.onChange(e.target.dataset.valueAsNumber)}
               step={props.step}
    />);
}
```